# Remove duplicate JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, multiple-instances

I have a JFrame on which there is a JButton. When the JButton is clicked it will create a new frame, so there are two visible frames. What I want is that when I click the JButton again, rather than creating a new JFrame it just brings the old frame to the front.

How do I check for that will only be one new frame created? Or is there another way?

Comment: Post some code because the way you are handling the event and what you want to achieve is hard to understand.

Comment: Can you post an SSCCE. I think that your solution might be use of modal dialogs. If I understood your question well...

Comment: So you want the first button press to create a new frame, but every button press after the first to bring the second frame to the foreground?

Comment: @Dunes: yes, that's what I mean

Comment: You could simply add a boolean which is standard set to false. Set it to true when the button is clicked the first time and add a check whether or not the variable is true or false. If it's false => Create a jframe, if it's true => show the jframe.

Comment: @Jeroen: can you show that code?

Answer (score 2):

> so how do I make that check, so that the frame is already open there
>   is no duplicate, or is there another way?

- no good idea to create a two [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html), nor bunch of `JFrame`s, this is road to throubles
- see [Oracles tutorial How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), [a few Q&A on this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+cardlayout)
- in the case (real and important reasons) that you need another popup window, then to use [JDialog or JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), [JDialog with `setModal()`/`ModalityTypes` and with parent to `JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Dialog,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to get the button or the parent of the button to keep track of whether a new frame had been created. The best way to do this is to keep a reference to the frame.

eg.

```
public class MyGUI {

    private JFrame primaryFrame;
    private JFrame secondFrame;
    private JButton someButton;

    public void setupAndDisplay() {
        // initialise the button
        someButton = new JButton("some button");
        someButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                someButtonAction();
            }
        });

        // initialise primary JFrame
        primaryFrame = new JFrame("first frame");
        primaryFrame.add(someButton);
        primaryFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    // Like most swing stuff this method is not thread safe, as it expects to 
    // only be called on the EventDispatchThread.
    private void someButtonAction() {
        if (secondFrame == null) { // no frame created yet, so create a new one
            secondFrame = new JFrame("second frame");
            secondFrame.setVisible(true);
        } else { // already have a frame, so bring it to the front
            secondFrame.toFront(); 
        }
    }
}
```

This might not be the best way to do things. If you are trying to do something quite simple, like maybe a dialog window, then the chances are the API has simpler ways to help you out. So you should explore your options and think about what you need to do before you choose this path.

NB. I haven't tested this code, it's just for illustrative purposes to show you how to set things up.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean hasWindow = false;

if(hasWindow){
// show existing window
hasWindow = true;
} else {
// create a new window
hasWindow = true;
}
```

Something along these lines.

Answer (score -3):

you set the visible to false thats all